# Delphi fast plus big integer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
function AddNumStrings (Str1, Str2 : string): string;
var
  i : integer;
  carryStr : string;
  worker : integer;
  workerStr,s : string;

  begin
  Result := inttostr (length(Str1));
  Result := '';
  carryStr := '0';

  // make numbers the same length
 s:=StringofChar('0',Length(Str1)-1);
 Str2:=s+Str2;

  i := 0;
  while i < length(Str1) do
  begin
    worker := strtoint(copy(Str1, length(str1)-i, 1)) +
              strtoint(copy(Str2, length(str2)-i, 1)) +
              strtoint (carryStr);
    if worker > 9 then
    begin
      workerStr := inttostr(worker);
      carryStr := copy(workerStr, 1, 1);
      result := copy(workerStr, 2, 1) + result;
    end
    else
    begin
      result := inttostr(worker) + result;
      carryStr := '0';
    end;


    inc(i);
  end; { while }
  if carryStr <> '0' then
    result := carryStr + result;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
s,z:String;
begin
s:='1000';
repeat
s:=AddNumStrings(s,'1');

until
Length(s)=1000;


ShowMessage(s);
end;

end.
```

But this codes takes too time. Is there any options to fastest way for my codes?
I m working huge number so I have to write "Inc()" procedure manually for huge number billion digits. I know what you think about it bu I have to do it. Thank you..

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I m working about huge fibonacci number and prime number.

Comment: Google for "delphi large integer library" or similar - I'm pretty sure this has been done before.

Comment: I m searching for 4 years :) Really, but I couldnt do it. May be here ı can solve my problem.

Comment: I used samo library, yes I can work huge numbers, but When I plus twu numbers that takes too time. How can I d it faster? Just plus(+) operation. Thank you..

Comment: Pal,  If it really would be possible, someone would implemented it decade ago. So either you would find non-Delphi (c, fortran,...) lib that you can make Delphi wrapper for. Or you create a custom hardware like those programmable gate arrays. Or it is bad luck. PS I wonder if someone tried that GPGPU style. GPUs are bad at branching, but they are very  SIMDy

Comment: One general advice : if that function is called frequently,  then all those Copy and StringOfChar should be avoided. Even in later Delphi powered by FastCode and FastMM heap allocations and concatenation are significant work to do. Better code your custom and optimised StrToInt (string, integer, integer) that does not copy anything but only reads characters. Even better would be to make comparisons all-text without integer-string conversions at all. Later Delphi versions can also help you by having FastCode and FastMM out of the box,  inline functions and OmniThreads library

Comment: 4 years?!! What are you talking about? Use GMP.

Comment: It's taken me no more than 4 days to find any library I've needed. And even that's too long.

Comment: You won't get very far studying primes if addition is the only operation you have. One wonders what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

1. [**INT128**](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,17273.15.html) lib for FPC
2. [**GNURZ**](http://forge.lazarusforum.de/projects/show/gnurz) lib (for FPC but should be compatible with Delphi)
3. [**GMP**](https://gmplib.org/#DOC) (FPC [supports it](http://wiki.freepascal.org/gmp), Delphi [also](https://www.google.rs/search?q=gmp%20delphi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=kk_KUuHEN6esyAP1xYCwAg))
4. [**BigInt**](http://delphiforfun.org/programs/Math_Topics/Pell%20and%20Continued%20Fractions.htm) and [**BigFloat**](http://delphiforfun.org/programs/Math_Topics/Pell%20and%20Continued%20Fractions.htm)
5. [**BigInt Delphi Library**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bigint-dl/)
6. Another [**BigInt**](http://www.idogendel.com/docs/projects/BigInt.zip)
7. **[TPMath](http://www.unilim.fr/pages_perso/jean.debord/tpmath/tpmath.htm)**
8. [**DeHL**](https://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/) for Delphi
9. [**BigNumbers**](https://github.com/rvelthuis/BigNumbers) BigInteger, BigDecimal and BigRational for Delphi

Hopefully one of those will be faster...