# Pascal: how to compare big numbers

Tags: string, performance, comparison, pascal, long-integer

I have strings which contain integers, which may be lerger than maxInt, and I need to compare them, so what would be the best way to do this.
here is the example off my code :

```
   x := 1;
   Reset(File1);
   While Not eof(File1) do
   Begin
      Read(File1, num[i]);
      Inc(i)
   End;
   z := i;
   w := z + 1;
   j := z + 1;
   While Not eof(File1) do
   Begin
      Read(File1, num[j]);
      Inc(j)
   End;
   y := j;
   If
   If j > i Then a := 1 Else If j = i Then
   Begin
      While z <> x do
      Begin
         If  Ord(num[j]) > Ord(num[i]) Then a := 1 Else If Ord(num[j]) < Ord(num[i]) Then a := 0;
         Dec(j);
         Dec(i)
      End;
   End Else a := 0;
   If a = 1 Then
   Begin
      x := z+1;
      z := y
   End;
```

Answer (score 3):

If the only thing you want to do is compare the strings which contains numbers possibly larger than the compiler has built-in routines for, you could compare the strings themselves.

Comparing length first and if same, comparing the characters from left to right would be a good strategy.

***NB. If your strings contains trailing or leading spaces, leading zeroes, remove them before comparing.***

Here is an example using a stringlist to sort the values (as strings) in ascending order (Should work in Delphi and freepascal):

```
program ProjTestBigIntSort;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes;

type
  TMyStringList = class(TStringList)
  protected
    function CompareStrings(const S1, S2: string): Integer; override;
  end;

function TMyStringList.CompareStrings(const S1, S2: string): Integer;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  // Trimming leading/trailing spaces and leading zeroes might be needed first
  Result := 0;
  // Compare length, shortest sorts first
  if (Length(S1) > Length(S2)) then begin
    Result := 1;
    Exit;
  end;
  if (Length(S1) < Length(S2)) then begin
    Result := -1;
    Exit;
  end;
  // Same length, compare digits from left to right:
  i := 1;
  while (i <= Length(S1)) do begin
    if (Ord(S1[i]) < Ord(S2[i])) then begin
      Result := -1;
      Exit;
    end
    else
    if (Ord(S1[i]) > Ord(S2[i])) then begin
      Result := 1;
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  SL: TMyStringList;
  s: String;
begin
  SL:= TMyStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add('1');
    SL.Add('99999999999999999999999999999');
    SL.Add('88888888888888888888888888888');
    SL.Add('99999999999999999999');
    SL.Sort;
    for s in SL do WriteLn(s);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  Test;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Output:

```
1
99999999999999999999
88888888888888888888888888888
99999999999999999999999999999
```

**Update:**

If the numbers can be negative, that could be fixed by this comparison test:

```
function TMyStringList.CompareStrings(const S1, S2: string): Integer;
var
  i : Integer;
  cmpNegative : Boolean;
const
  cNeg : array[boolean] of Integer = (1,-1);
begin
  // Trimming leading/trailing spaces and leading zeroes might be needed first
  Result := 0;
  cmpNegative := false;
  // Test for negative numbers
  if (S1[1] = '-') then begin
    if (S2[1] <> '-') then begin
      Result := -1;
      Exit;
    end;
    // Both numbers negative, reverse comparison
    cmpNegative := true;
  end
  else
  if (S2[1] = '-') then begin
    Result := 1;
    Exit;
  end;
  // Compare length, shortest sorts first
  if (Length(S1) > Length(S2)) then begin
    Result := 1*cNeg[cmpNegative];
    Exit;
  end;
  if (Length(S1) < Length(S2)) then begin
    Result := -1*cNeg[cmpNegative];
    Exit;
  end;
  i := 1;
  while (i <= Length(S1)) do begin
    if (Ord(S1[i]) < Ord(S2[i])) then begin
      Result := -1*cNeg[cmpNegative];
      Exit;
    end
    else
    if (Ord(S1[i]) > Ord(S2[i])) then begin
      Result := 1*cNeg[cmpNegative];
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

---

Should you need to do arithmetic operations on the values, consider using a big integer package. See [Delphi fast plus big integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944664/576719)

Comment: Despite my up vote, I just thought of negative numbers and handling minus signs too.

Comment: @LURD already linked to a list. I'd like to recommend my [BigNumbers](https://github.com/rvelthuis/BigNumbers): Docs [start here](http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html).

Comment: @MarkSetchell, thanks, added a test for negative numbers as well.